# Datatables comparison on 1 or 2 columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have 2 datatables with different rows, one of the column is common

I want to find the common values which are found in table1 but not in table 2 by comparing the common column only...

EDIT - added tab structure

Table1

```
Col1 col2 col3 col4 
1     z    x    y
2     a    s    d
3     3    2    1
4     !    @    4
```

table 2

```
col1   col2 
1       q
2       w
3       e
4       t
5       %
6       y
```

result1

```
col1
1
2
3
4
```

result2

```
col1
5
6
```

Comment: You want to do a left outer join. There's plenty of questions/answers on this site for doing this in linq so pop that into a search. Good luck!

Comment: Could you include the structure of your tables? What have you tried so far?